# Semantics of Objective-C Methods

Tags: objective-c, methods

Coming from a Java background, I'm still don't quite understand the *semantics* of Objective-C methods as opposed to their *syntax*. Take as an example the following method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

Easy enough. There is a method named *numberOfSectionsInTableView* which takes a *UITableView* as a parameter and returns a *NSInteger*. Now, how about these methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

How should I interpret these methods? I've stumbled upon three possible explanations:

1) All three the methods are named *tableView* and they are overloaded with different parameters. This seems unlikely as people talk about 'calling the *numberOfRowsInSection* method'.

2) The methods are named *numberOfRowsInSection*, *heightForRowAtIndexPath* and *cellForRowAtIndexPath*, and the *tableView* is an artifact due to delegation. In that case, what exactly does the *tableView* part mean syntactically? If the format of a method is '(return)name:parameters, where does *tableView* fit in?

3) As Objective-C uses message passing, it's wrong to think about methods. Rather think about passing messages to the object directly. In other words, if the object receives the messages named *tableView* and *numberOfRowsInSection*, it knows to execute a certain part of the code. If this is the case, does order matter? Is passing *numberOfRowsInSection* and *tableView* the same as passing *tableView* and *numberOfRowsInSection*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name (or selector, in Objective-C's parlance) of a method includes all of the parts of the name. For example, look at these three methods, all of which can coexist in the same class:

```
- (void)foo;                       // named 'foo'
- (void)foo:(int)bar;              // named 'foo:'
- (void)foo:(int)bar baz:(int)qux; // named 'foo:baz:'
```

Note the colon in the name of the version of "foo" that takes a parameter: that's crucial. The number of parameters that a method takes is part of its name. This is actually strictly defined, because at times in Objective-C you need to refer to the full selector of a method (using the `@selector` directive). See the [Selectors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocSelectors.html) section of the Objective-C Programming Language document.

Additionally, the order is significant. These two methods are different:

```
- (void)foo:(int)bar baz:(int)qux; // named 'foo:baz:'
- (void)baz:(int)quz foo:(int)bar; // named 'baz:foo:'
```

There is no overloading in Objective-C. The compiler won't dispatch to different methods with the same name but different parameter types.

The leading `tableView:` in your examples is simply a common naming convention used for delegates; all delegate selectors will start with a parameter that specifies the object that is delegating functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C the method names are referred to as [*signatures*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_signature) and the methods are often called [*selectors*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocSelectors.html).

The signature of the four selectors in your example are.

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView:
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:tableView:` is not the same as `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

There cannot be more than one selector with the same signature per class.

Comment: Actually, no.  In Objective-C, the method name is the selector.  Methods are called "methods".  The signature refers to the method name and the types of the arguments.

Comment: @JeremyP: method signature does not know the method name

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, the arguments are interspersed with the method name (called the "selector") instead of passed as a list in parentheses after the name. The full selector is that whole long thing (tableView:numberOfRowaInSection:). The selector is split at the colons and that's where the arguments are placed. There is one argument for each colon. A selector without any colons signifies a method that takes no parameters.